# After clicking on button fetch method is called endlessly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to use a modal within a 'use client' page.tsx. I use this example for this: https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/tailwind-starter-kit/documentation/react/modals/regular. However, if I click on the button, my fecth call is set in an endless loop and called indefinitely, the app hangs. What's the problem here?
I use Next in the 13.4.3 Version.

app/page.tsx:

```
"use client";

export default async function Home() {
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/products`, {
 cache: "no-store",
}).then((res) => res.json());


  <button
      className="bg-pink-500 text-white active:bg-pink-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
      type="button"
      onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
      Open regular modal
  </button>
...

}
```

after click on button:

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rreact+fetch+and+display+data&oq=rreact+fetch+and+display+data&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13i512j0i22i30l3j0i390i650l5.1818j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bsht=Cgdic2h3Y2hwEgQIBDAB

Comment: ehm, no... Why?

Comment: I didn't write that. The system automatically inserts a comment with that text when someone votes to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: It is, whether you realize it or not, and since this already is gathering downvotes and close votes I suggest you very quickly and convincingly explain why you feel that way.

Comment: @Captai-N: I'm surprised the button (or any UI for this component) rendered at all.  React components can't be `async`.  And you *definitely* don't want to perform an AJAX operation *on every render*.  If you want to fetch data from the server when the component first renders, put that operation inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making an AJAX request *on every render* of the component.  That's probably not what you want.

Instead, use `useEffect` to make the AJAX request on the *first* render (or any time a given set of dependencies changes, which doesn't appear to be the case here) and update state with the result.  For example:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  useEffect(function () {
    (async function() {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/products`, {
        cache: "no-store",
      });
      const json = await res.json();
      setResult(json);
    })();
  }, []);

  // the rest of the component...

}
```